# hibernate criteria api how to get Path from fetched records?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I have a query written in criteria api that goes like this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Application> query = builder.get().createQuery(Application.class).distinct(true);

Root<Application> root = query.from(Application.class);

root.fetch(Application_.answerSets, JoinType.LEFT);
```

I need to get Path for `answerSet.createDate` field, but have no idea how to achieve it. I need it to make a query for applications where answer sets are older than X days.

Answer (score 0):

Try `query.add(Restrictions.eq("answerSet.createDate", YOURVALUE))`. However I am not if `createQuery` is the same as `createCriteria`.